# Is it possible to save a custom audio device setup in MS Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

In Microsoft Teams (primarily used on Windows but Mac as well), I often switch between 2 audio setups: my Jabra headset, and my desktop speakers + webcam mic. In Teams, I can easily select the headset, in the **Audio Devices** dropdown menu (Device Settings->Audio Settings->Audio devices), but if I want to switch to the other config, I have to manually select the Speaker and Microphone. Is there a way to save my custom config as a new Audio Device, so I don't have to manually select each time?